# Converting XML to Array, and then looping through some objects results in 'Illegal string offset' if there's only a single object

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Before this gets marked as a duplicate, please know that my issue is slightly different to the normal `Illegal string offset` issue.

I have some XML which is an order dispatch notification. I convert to it to JSON and then to an array. Then I loop through the line items and add them to a MySQL database.

This works great when there are multiple items to loop through. When there is just 1 item, it returns the `Illegal string offset` error.

I've rewrote the code to simulate the issue here:

```
echo "SINGLE ITEM: \r\n";
$xmlstring = '<dispatch_notification>' .
        '    <line_items>' .
        '            <sku>N123456789</sku>' .
        '            <barcode></barcode>' .
        '            <quantity>1</quantity>' .
        '    </line_items>' .
        '</dispatch_notification>' .
        '';
processXML($xmlstring);


echo "\r\n\r\nMULTIPLE ITEMS: \r\n";
$xmlstring = '<dispatch_notification>' .
        '    <line_items>' .
        '            <sku>N123456789</sku>' .
        '            <barcode></barcode>' .
        '            <quantity>1</quantity>' .
        '    </line_items>' .
        '    <line_items>' .
        '            <sku>O123456789</sku>' .
        '            <barcode></barcode>' .
        '            <quantity>5</quantity>' .
        '    </line_items>' .
        '</dispatch_notification>' .
        '';
processXML($xmlstring);

function processXML($xmlstring) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstring, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA);
    $dispatchedOrder = json_decode(json_encode($xml), TRUE);
    foreach ($dispatchedOrder['line_items'] as $item) {//loop through each line item
        echo $item['sku'] . ", " . $item['quantity'] . "\r\n";
    }
}
```

This outputs:

> SINGLE ITEM:
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'sku' in
> /testing/xmltest.php on line 47
>
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'quantity' in /testing/xmltest.php on
> line 47 N, N , Warning: Illegal string offset 'sku' in
> /testing/xmltest.php on line 47
>
> Warning: Illegal string offset 'quantity' in /testing/xmltest.php on
> line 47 1, 1
>
> MULTIPLE ITEMS:  N123456789, 1  O123456789, 5

This shows that it worked fine when looping through the `line_items` object when there are multiple but not a single one.

I also tried the XML in this format but this had the same issue.

```
<line_items>
    <item>
        <sku>M7389462334</sku>
        <barcode></barcode>
        <quantity>1</quantity>
    </item>
    <item>
        <sku>L67858745445</sku>
        <barcode></barcode>
        <quantity>1</quantity>
    </item>
</line_items>
```

I'm a bit stumped as to why this is happening, I don't often work with XML, usually JSON so I'm not sure if this is to do with the formatting of the XML or something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have some XML ... I convert to it to JSON and then to an array.

Don't do that. XML, JSON, and PHP arrays all have different ideas about how data can and should be structured. Blindly converting between them is just a bad idea.

Instead, look at the [usage examples for SimpleXML](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) and see how easy it makes it to work with XML.

Here is a working version of your code:

```
function processXML($xmlstring) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstring);
    foreach ($xml->line_items as $item) {
        echo $item->sku . ", " . $item->quantity . "\r\n";
    }
}
```

Note that I've got rid of the "LIBXML_NOCDATA" option as well - it's frequently misused due to a misunderstanding of how SimpleXML works, and a quirk in its debug output.

Comment: Thanks for this. Almost every search for converting XML to array showed to convert to JSON and back again and I hated it. Especially when empty strings became empty objects. I knew there had to be another easier way.

Comment: @user2924019 Yes, it frustrates me that that nasty hack has become so widespread. I think the problem is that everyone assumes they need it _as an array_, whereas what SmipleXML gives you is an _object_ which is _better_ than an array (because it has helpers to access the data in multiple ways).

Comment: I've just remembered why I need it as an array however... I need to normalize the data into an array to return the array for a main process script to process the dispatch notifications. You see, this is my handler for XML files, there's other sources which would be JSON, or some other library that returns orders as a custom object etc. I will use your method above to loop through and turn into an array this way.

Comment: @user2924019 Then normalise it to an array _with a structure of your choice_, using code like the above. In other words, treat the XML as though it was a black box you can pull data out of, just like if it was an object from a library you had no control over. Where people fall down is trying to make a _single_ function that can work with _every_ XML format, which is doomed to failure.

Comment: Thanks for this, all implemented now. It will be processing orders for a well known UK online retailer by the end of the week! - Actually several technically.